# How to write a solr query

Tags: json, solr

I am trying to write a solr query to an API to search for specific tickets and get the search data back in JSON format. One of the attributes is a long string containing special characters. How should I write it?

Here is the line making the error, and thus returning 0 tickets:

> assignedTo:tbw:ctv::76987684564353:user/Test-USER-Here

The normal user-string which is searched for is: 'tbw:ctv::76987684564353:user/Test-USER-Here'

I tried to escape the special characters above but it returns 0 documents.

A second question, how to search for a string starting with "tbw" for example?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does the document in Solr look like? A query like `assignedTo:"tbw:ctv::76987684564353:user/Test-USER-Here"` should be able to find the document - and you probably want this to be a string field, since you're only looking for exact matches. Getting JSON back can be done by appending `wt=json` to your query url

Comment: No it's somehow not working.. And I am sure it should return documents. How would I write it if I want to search for strings ending with "Here"?

Comment: In that case you'll have to use a wildcard - if the field is a string field - `*Here`. But usually this is better implemented by using a `ReverseWildcardFilter` and a KeywordTokenizer - or depending on usage, an ngramfilter. Matching wil be beased on the field type, so as mentioned you'll want a string field for matching exact values.

Comment: what does  `assignedTo:tbw\:ctv\:\:76987684564353\:user/Test-USER-Here`  yeild?

Answer (score 0):

You can search for a string starting with a particular letter in solr using the query string: **tbw***

[This is An Amazing tutorial on solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_7/solr-tutorial.html)